# Npm i command running continuously

Tags: npm

I am new to iconic framework, to install iconic,downloaded node.js and then follow steps and in command prompt type npm install -g cordova ionic command, but it gives security error not able to install

Comment: _ionic_ or _iconic_?

Comment: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents): error coming